# Assign recursive children to list using c# and linq

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have a class

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Options MyOptions { get; set; }
}

public class Options
{
    public IEnumerable<Options> Children { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryOptions { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying for a recursive function where

```
public static MyModel MapDetails()
{
    MyOptions.Children.Foreach(x => 
    if(!string.IsNullorEmtpy(x.SecondaryOptions))
    {
        x.Children = GetChild(x.SecondaryOptions, x);
    });
}
 
public static IEnumerable<Options> GetChild(string path, Options child)
{
    var childlist = optionsList; //based on path we will get this 

    childlist.Children.Foreach(child => 
    if(!string.IsNullorEmtpy(child.SecondaryOptions))
    {
        //should be called for each children recursively
        child.Children = GetChild(child.SecondaryOptions, child);
    });
}
```

This is not working as expected. And somehow the children is getting lost during the iteration.

I am expecting the output to have,

```
MyOptions.Children-
 A
   aa
     aaa
     aab
   ab
   ac
 B
   ba
   bb
 C
```

The loop should iterate and for each item if it has secondary options string, based on string we will get list of items which we need to assign against that particular iteration Child

(i.e) A-has children aa,ab,ac. aa has children aaa, aab. aaa, aab should be mapped to aa.Children and aa,ab,ac should be mapped to
A.Children.
How do I achieve this using linq c#?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Why do you think Linq is a magical solution to this?

Comment: Can you add the code how you setup your Model? It may that the error is in that part.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.